Is this minesweeper solvable? it's supposed to

I know sometimes it is just a matter of guessing, but this game was in the website mineswifter.com which has boards made by AI that eliminate the guessing of the game.

It depends.. how many mines are missing? Because you surely need to put 2 flags, if no more are needed you are free to open the upper right tile
